# How to use jQuery with in xhtml?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, xhtml, facelets

i am using facelets,richfaces,and ajax, in XHTML
i am facing error while creating datepicker!
What is the solution for my problem?
**the code is:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich">

    <head>

<a4j:loadScript src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
<a4j:loadScript src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h:form>
  <rich:panel>
  <h:inputText id="mydate" value="" label="test" size="20"/>
  <rich:jQuery selector="#mydate" name="mydate" query="datepicker({changeMonth:true,changeYear:true})" timing="onload"/>


  </rich:panel>
  </h:form>



 </body>

</html>
```

**error i am getting is:**

```
 INFO: Added Library from: jar:file:/D:/WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/RichTest/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar!/META-INF/ajax4jsf.taglib.xml
Oct 8, 2010 1:51:30 PM com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js]
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:234)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Oct 8, 2010 1:51:30 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl phase
WARNING: executePhase(RENDER_RESPONSE 6,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@19e733e) threw exception
com.sun.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:234)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Oct 8, 2010 1:51:30 PM org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter doXmlFilter
SEVERE: Exception in the filter chain
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js: Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
```

Please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem is :
**How to use jQuery with in xhtml?**

**My Answer is:**
1.Create an xhtml page using code given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich">

    <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
<a4j:loadStyle src="/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" />
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js" />     
  </head>
  <body >      
  <h:form>
  <rich:panel>
  <h:inputText id="dp1" value="" label="test"  />
  <rich:jQuery  selector="#dp1" name="dp1" rendered="true" timing="onload" query="datepicker({chosendate:'01/05/2005',minYear:'-20Y',maxDate: '+1Y +1M',appendText: '(dd-mm-yyyy)',changeMonth:true,changeYear:true})" ></rich:jQuery>        
  </rich:panel>
  </h:form>    
 </body>    
</html>
```

**2.then try to place *JQuery.xx.js & css* files below order!**

---WebContent
   +themes
   +....
   ...jquery-1.4.2.min.js
   ...jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css
   ...jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js

all these are configured in .xhtml file like above.

**3.General things we need to configure for facelets, richfaces and ajax in web.xml is common,in all the way.**
**4.At last it worked Perfectly...**
Thank You Guy's..

Answer (score 3):

According to http://seamframework.org/Community/HowToWriteJavaScriptInXHTML you only need to:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>
```

Comment: Hi Blair McMillan, Thank You for your Kind Information. Your answer really helped me to find out the problem. I worked more than two hours to get exact result, at-last i find the procedure. That is given Below.....!

Comment: Excellent. Glad it got you on track.