# location of jquery.js file

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have created a sample jsf application, and am trying to use jquery. In what directory should the jquery.js file be located? web-inf? src? I downloaded the .js file, but it does not seem to be working. I'm not sure where it should be.

I have updated my code to point to the googleapis, but it still does not work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
                alert("You entered p1!");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <p id="p1">Enter this paragraph.</p>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt matter, the most important is you have to give the correct path.

For example:

```
<script language="javascript" src='script/jquery-1.6.min.js'></script>
```

And your html file which includes jquery must be put alongside with the script folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it anywhere as long as you give correct path to the file. But try to keep it away from the `WEB-INF` directory, keep only private file under that directory (files which are not directly accessible to users).

If you have a `web-content` directory, keep the jquery file under `web-content\js` directory, so that you can access it via `<path-to-your-app>/js/jquery.js`.

But if you can try to use a CDN version of the file as given in the [download section](http://jquery.com/download/) of jQuery. You can use either [Google](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js) or [Microsoft](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js) CDNs.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using JSF2, you can utilize the JSF2 resource management system. That is, drop the CSS/JS/image resources in `/resources` folder of public webcontent like so:

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    |-- css
 |    |    `-- style.css
 |    |-- js
 |    |    `-- script.js
 |    `-- img
 |         `-- logo.png
 :
```

Which are then available by the following components:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
<h:outputScript name="js/script.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="img/logo.png" />
```

In your particular case, you thus need to save it as `/resources/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js`:

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- js
 |         `-- jquery-1.9.0.min.js
 :
```

And reference it as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript target="body">
        $("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
            alert("You entered p1!");
        });
    </h:outputScript>
    <p id="p1">Enter this paragraph.</p>
</h:body>
```

Note: the `<h:outputScript target="body">` will be autorelocated to end of `<body>` which will be hit sooner than `$(document).ready()`.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code/)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter as long as you are supplying the right path , for now mostly we use google hosted jquery library . which takes off some of the traffic pressure ..

you can try it
[google hosted library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

please note that you will need to put an http or https before the link ..

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the script files in `WebResources`/`WebContent` folder(any resource folder, but path must be correct),
using `h:outputScript` to load script file:([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095727/1213738))

```
 <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-1.6.2.js" />
```

placing path if you are using RichFaces:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///pathToFile/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
```

Adding **Google CDN**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Reference: [jQuery in xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888881/how-to-use-jquery-with-in-xhtml)
**Your Scenario:** Use code like below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
                alert("You entered p1!");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <p id="p1">Enter this paragraph.</p>
</h:body>
```

**Or**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#p1").mouseenter(function(){
                    alert("You entered p1!");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**Demo:**
 [Live Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/z6BYs/)(adding google CDN in body)
[Live Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/CaFKY/) (adding google CDN in header).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the jquery library in `WebContent` directory inside the `resources` folder in your web application.

```
WebContent
   ->resources->js->jquery-latest-version.js
```

and you can include the jquery in JSF page by specifying,

```
<h:outputScript name="js/jquery-latest-version.js" />
```

within html `<head>` or at the bottom of the page as well.

Comment: This is improper usage of resource library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used Just use `<h:outputScript name="js/jquery-latest-version.js" />`

Answer (score 0):

In your web-app add folder `resources` next folder `js` next folder named by your JavaScript file as `jquery.js` and inside this valid JavaScript file with name matching the syntax of version, for example `1_6.js`.

So for your example it will be:

```
<your_web_app>/resources/js/jquery_min.js/1_6.js
```

This is a correct JSF way. Now you can use in your jsf pages:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery_min.js"/>
```

And all versions will be managed by JSF Framework. If you add next version, maybe 1_7 so file named `1_7.js` to your `jquery_min.js` folder then JSF will automaticall make call from above code to that version of file.

Comment: This is improper usage of resource library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used Just use `<h:outputScript name="js/jquery_min.js"/>`

Comment: Please, in few words say me why? I read your question and self ansewer ;) in this link and still won't catch what you have in mind?

Comment: "js" does not represent a proper library name.

Comment: Why? See JSF 2.2 Specification pages 75-81 (from 7 December 2012). Why for specification authors `images` is good name for library and is used as example and You said that `js` or `javascript` is not good? Isn't this case of web-app developer to decided how to named library?

Comment: Surely it'll work. That's not a technical problem. The functional problem is, if all component libraries use an overly generic term like "js" for their collection of JS files, how would you in the resource handler distinguish the component library vendor if necessary?

Comment: Also in your answer to this question You suggest to use `name` attribute instead of `library` + `name` as `js` + `file_name.js`? Is it realy intuitive for you to named file as `js/file_name.js` instead of `file_name.js`. Is a name to doc file on Win Desktop a `Desktop/file.doc` or just `file.doc`? `library` attr, for me, was introducted exactly to difference files by their types and destiny. So .css files are destinied to be in css library, .js file to be in javascript library and so on? Isn't it true?

Comment: No, the `library` attribute is not to distinguish the file type. It's to distinguish the library. Otherwise that attribute was named `type` or so.

Comment: But in spec authors distinguish images in `images` library, why?

Comment: That was just a bad example.

Comment: Think in that way: if I named my library other way than I did it till now, so `javascript` and `css` and so on, there can comes some misunderstanding. In case when I have to files named the same but with other types (.css and .js) and have them in library `layout` how easy is to use in `name` attr wrong file by just missleading type of file?