# How to include external Javascript file in a JSF page

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I want to include the URL of jQuery UI **http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js** in my JSF page. I saw many questions which said `<h:outputScript>` should be used, but in none of the answers I saw an example as to how to include an URL. The answers were only relevant if the js file is present in some folder of the project.

Can someone please help where I have to include it in my page?

Comment: perhaps similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493689/location-of-jquery-js-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use plain HTML `<script>` element the usual way.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The `<h:outputScript>` can only refer local scripts. You'll only miss its dynamic versioning, modularity and relocation advantages, but that should technically not harm for a static and external script.

It's however possible to use a custom `ResourceHandler` to change the URL of a `<h:outputScript>` to be an external URL for pure CDN purposes. [OmniFaces `CDNResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler) is such an example.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, PrimeFaces components are built around jQuery/UI. Are you *absolutely* positive that you need a separate instance of jQuery UI library?

Comment: I do. Because I have to use jQueryUI's sortable functionality. And, there is a bug with the auto scrolling in sortable bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7546. Have a look at the JSFiddle links provided there.

Comment: I am guessing Primefaces uses jQuery library's old version, so the auto scroll problem persists.