# place external JavaScript after CSS file inside head element using JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

I use JSF 2.3 for developing web application.
As a web developer, I care about the performance of loading speed of a site.

As I was exploring on how I could make my site faster, I encountered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448973/is-ordering-of-link-rel-stylesheet-and-script-tags-significant) on Stack Overflow. And the quote from the accepted and most up-voted answer said

> stylesheets should always be specified in the head of a document for better performance, it's important, where possible, that any external JS files that must be included in the head (such as those that write to the document) follow the stylesheets, to prevent delays in download time.

I know that JavaScript performs better when it is placed at the bottom of the `<body>`, but I want to include reCAPTCHA and Google instructs us to place the required external JavaScript before the closing `</head>` tag.

So, I decided to include the required external JavaScript before the closing `</head>` tag and after CSS files to boost the performance.

However, my CSS files are declared in a JSF way like `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css"/>`, and I realized that the CSS files declared this way are always placed after files that are declared in a non-JSF way, which is `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`. I also considered making the external JavaScript behave in a JSF way by changing `<script>` to `<h:outputScript>`, but the `<h:outputScript>` can only render local scripts as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748145/how-to-include-external-javascript-file-in-a-jsf-page) .

So, the result will always be as follows.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/javax.faces.resource/css/default.css.xhtml" />
</head>
```

insted of

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/javax.faces.resource/css/default.css.xhtml" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
```

Maybe I'm thinking too much, and the placement order of `link` and `script` doesn't affect the performance that much, but if the loading speed gets faster even a little, I want to follow the better way.

Comment: Did you read about the Omnifaces CDNResourceHandler? As referred to in the post you refer to?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I wasn't paying attention to Omnifaces solution. It displayed in the correct order when I used CDNResourceHandler. Thank you.